# Selecting documents from the end of the collection use MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework

I need to get a list of messages from the end, the last 50 that fall under the condition:

```js
$match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$chat_id",
              "b199ceba-78bb-4204-859e-5a1be228b2b5"
            ]
          },
          {
            $lte: [
              "$create_date",
              1675411054031 // is the value for the test, the really data comes from the client
            ],
            
          },
          
        ]
      },
      
    }
```

In my example, the working version of [A working example, absolutely I also want to get data using aggregations in golang](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-t_O_YwjDBc)

BUT my golang variant using aggregation returns messages starting from the beginning of the collection, from the very first. How can I get messages from the very end?

```golang
func (r *Mongo) ChatHistory(ctx context.Context, chatID string, f *Filter) ([]*Message, error) {
    sortQueryStage := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$sort", Value: bson.D{
                primitive.E{Key: "create_date", Value: -1},
            },
        },
    }
    matchStage := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$match",
            Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "chat_id", Value: chatID},
                {Key: "create_date", Value: bson.D{
                    {
                        Key:   "$lte",
                        Value: 1675411054031, // int64
                    }},
                },
            },
        },
    }
    sortStage := bson.D{
        {
            Key: "$sort", Value: bson.D{
                primitive.E{Key: "create_date", Value: 1},
            },
        },
    }
    limitStage := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "$limit", Value: f.Count}}
    cursor, err := r.colMessage.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{matchStage, sortQueryStage, sortStage, limitStage})
    if err != nil {
        l.Error().Err(err).Msg("failed find")
        return nil, err
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Simply sort descending? So the first 50 documents are the last 50 of the original order. `{Key: "create_date", Value: -1}`

Comment: @icza, If you look at my code I wrote in golang, you'll see that I have this sorting, but it didn't help me at all

Comment: It looks like you are sorting twice. The first time is descending (`sortQueryStage`) which is what you want, but the second time is ascending (`sortStage`)....So your results is according to the second sort...I think that if you remove the `sortStage` you will get what you want

Comment: As @nimrodserok wrote: remove the second sorting and leave only the value with `-1`.

Comment: @nimrodserok, Yes I tried that, but then I get the answer in descending order: from the last 50 messages, and I need to return in ascending order

Comment: In this case, the second sort should be **after** the `limitStage` step